# javascript function change style always just for the last click

Tags: javascript

```
  function change_color(sel)
   {
     var obj=document.getElementById(sel);
     obj.style.color='red';
     obj.style.fontWeight="bold";
   }
```

I have a list , like 150 rows. And if I select a row, I changed the color. But If I select more in one time, I want to changed always the last one. (Just one row can be colored)
What should I put in tihs function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a class instead. Then you can use `querySelector` to remove the class from the previously colored row, if it exists:

```
.clicked {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```
function change_color(sel){
  document.querySelector('.clicked')?.classList.remove('clicked');
  document.getElementById(sel).classList.add('clicked');
}
```

You could also store the previously toggled element in an outer variable.